# Android HERE SDK: adding file *.so inside jnilibs/armeabi

Tags: android, here-api, skmaps

I am using HERE Nokia Android SDK. I have jnilibs/armeabi folder with all files necessaries. Then I need to use another library and I have to put libngnative.so inside and create another folder: armeabi-v7a and x86 folder with libngnative.so too.

In my log I can see this message frome HERE: ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment: MISSING_LIBRARIES... and then my app crash.

If I remove libngnative.so from armeabi folder and I delete armeabi-v7a and x86 folders I have not this problem, but I need to use this library.

Can somebody help me please?

Regards

Comment: So you want to use both the Here SDK and the Telenav (skobbler) SDK?

Comment: Yes!! I need to use HERE and Telenav(Skobbler). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is inside of your APK file ?

The final APK should have something like this:

```
\libs\armeabi-v7a\libMAPSJNI.so
\libs\armeabi-v7a\libMapsEngineResources.so
\libs\armeabi-v7a\libXXXFont.so (There are a few of them)
```

If the HERE libraries are not in your APK, please check your gradle file?

Also, are there any library overlaps between the HERE library and your other native library?